# Finding an equation of the line perpendicular to the family of lines

Tags: geometry

With Euclidean coordinates I need to find the equation of the line perpendicular to the family of lines `y = x + λ` whereas `λ ∈ (-∞, ∞)` and at a distance `d` from the origin using only the terms of the parameters. What are the steps to do this?

A line is denoted with `y=ax+b` and a line perpendicular is `y=(-1/a)x+b` how can I apply this for a family of lines?

Is the answer simply: `y = (-1/x) + λ`? Where does distance d go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for the perpendicular line gives one result, yes. However, there is more than one line that is perpendicular to a given line, here you have to choose the right one.
Hint: In the final result, there should only be $d$ as an parameter, $\lambda$ should not appear. :)

Step 1: Draw your problem. Draw the lines for some $\lambda$ (say for example $\lambda = -2,-1,0,1,2$).

Step 2: Notice that all these lines are parallel, so taking the orthogonal of a single one of them will give a general result. Then compute this orthogonal.

Step 3: Change your result to match the required $d$.

Step 4 (important, don't forget this step!): Properly prove that the line you constructed is orthogonal to all other lines and has distance $d$, using the formulas you have for such things.